# How to update field value by determining each digit in field?

Tags: sql, oracle

Although I saw update statements to update field based on existing values, I could not find anything similar to this scenario:

Suppose you have a table with only one column of number(4) type.  The value in the first record is 1010.

```
create table stab(
  nmbr number(4)
);

insert into stab values(1010);

For each digit
   When the digit is 1 -- add 3 to the digit
   When the digit is 0 -- add four to the digit
end
```

This operations needs to be completed in a single statement without using pl/sql.

I think substr function need to be used but don't know how to go about completing this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DECODE(SUBSTR(nmbr,1,1), '1', 1 + 3, '0', 0 + 4) AS Decoded_Nmbr
FROM stab
ORDER BY Decoded_Nmbr
```

Is that what you are after?

Comment: Doubtful. The OP is after some sort of update, not a SELECT statement. Also, I don't see where there was any mention of ordering anything.

Comment: @NDin - Does this do what you requested? You said **for EACH digit** but this will only deal with the first digit. You said "update value", this is a SELECT. No wonder you won't get that job.

Answer (score 1):

So, it seems you need to convert every 0 and 1 to a 4, and leave all the other digits alone. This seems like a string operation (and the reference to "digits" itself suggests the same thing). So, convert the number to a string, use the Oracle `TRANSLATE` function (see the documentation), and convert back to number.

```
update stab
set    nmbr = to_number(translate(to_char(nmbr, '9999'), '01', '44'))
;
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming its always a 4 digit #; you could use substring like below 
-- postgres SQL example

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN a = 0 THEN a + 4
         ELSE a + 3
       end AS a,
       CASE
         WHEN b = 0 THEN b + 4
         ELSE b + 3
       end AS b,
       CASE
         WHEN c = 0 THEN c + 4
         ELSE c + 3
       end AS c,
       CASE
         WHEN d = 0 THEN d + 4
         ELSE c + 3
       end AS d
FROM   ( SELECT Substr( '1010', 1, 1 ) :: INT AS a,
                Substr( '1010', 2, 1 ) :: INT b,
                Substr( '1010', 3, 1 ) :: INT c,
                Substr( '1010', 4, 1 ) :: INT d )a
```

--- Other option may be (tried in postgreSQL :) ) to split the number using regexp_split_to_table  into rows;then add individual each digit based on the case statement and then concat the digits back into a string

```
SELECT array_to_string ( array
       (
              select
                     case
                            WHEN val = 0 THEN val +4
                            ELSE val +3
                     END
              FROM   (
                            SELECT regexp_split_to_table ( '101010','' ) ::INT val
                     ) a
       ) ,'' )
```

Comment: Why offer a Postgres solution (which will absolutely not work in Oracle) when the OP clearly tagged this as Oracle and mentions PL/SQL in the post (meaning, it is really Oracle, that's not a mistake)?

Comment: Thanks for the replies!  This was actually an interview question and they specified that it should be accomplished using SQL on Oracle WITHOUT use of PL/SQL.

Comment: Your input really helps, I modified the script as follows and find a way to update multiple records. The script below will only work on a single record:

Comment: update stble set nmbr=(
select decode(substr(nmbr,1,1),'1',3,'0',4) ||
          decode(substr(nmbr,2,1),'1',3,'0',5) ||
 decode(substr(nmbr,2,1),'1',3,'0',5) ||

Comment: update stble set nmbr=(
select decode(substr(nmbr,1,1),'1',3,'0',4) ||
          decode(substr(nmbr,2,1),'1',3,'0',4) ||
 decode(substr(nmbr,2,1),'1',3,'0',4) ||
 decode(substr(nmbr,2,1),'1',3,'0',4)  
from stble);

Comment: I just need to find out how to update multiple records at the same time.  I will try to do that myself, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

My answer to the interview question would have been that the DB design violates the rules of normalization (i.e. a bad design) and would not have this kind of "update anomaly" if it were properly designed.  Having said that, it can easily be done with an expression using various combinations of single row functions combined with the required arithmetic operations.